# JPA Order by with two columns

Tags: sql, database, jpa

I have two objects

Objects: Objeto, Comunicado and ComunicadoTramite

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objetos")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Objeto extends Fact {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_objeto", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dt_criacao")
    private Date dataCriacao;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comunicados")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cd_comunicado")
public class Comunicado extends Objeto {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comunicado")
    private List<ComunicadoTramite> tramites;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comunicados_tramites")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cd_tramite")
public class ComunicadoTramite extends Objeto {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cd_comunicado")
    private Comunicado comunicado;
```

The problem is, i want a list of Comunicado that is ordered by dataCriacao, the two objects (Comunicado and ComunicadoTramite) extends Objeto that contains dataCriacao.

if `Comunicado.tramites.size() > 0` then get dataCriacao from the last ComunicadoTramite inserted

if `Comunicado.tramites.size() = 0` then get dataCriacao from Comunicado.

SQL I did this

```
SELECT c.cd_comunicado, tb_tram.dt_criacao FROM comunicados AS c
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ct.cd_comunicado, MAX(obj.dt_criacao) AS dt_criacao FROM comunicados_tramites AS ct, objetos obj
                WHERE ct.cd_tramite = obj.id_objeto GROUP BY ct.cd_comunicado
            ) AS tb_tram
    ON c.cd_comunicado = tb_tram.cd_comunicado
)
UNION
(SELECT c.cd_comunicado, obj.dt_criacao FROM comunicados c, objetos obj 
    WHERE c.cd_comunicado = obj.id_objeto
        AND c.cd_comunicado NOT IN (SELECT tram.cd_comunicado FROM comunicados_tramites tram))
ORDER BY dt_criacao DESC
```

I dont know how to do it in JPA... can anyone help me?

Based on Jorge' ideas i did this

```
SELECT obj FROM Objeto obj 
    WHERE obj.id IN (select comunicado.id from Comunicado comunicado 
                        where comunicado NOT IN (SELECT tramite.comunicado from ComunicadoTramite tramite)) 
                OR obj.id IN(select tramite.id from ComunicadoTramite tramite
                where tramite.dataCriacao = (select MAX(tram.dataCriacao) from ComunicadoTramite tram WHERE tram.comunicado.id = tramite.comunicado.id)
                group by tramite.comunicado)
ORDER BY obj.dataCriacao DESC
```